# How to efficently create arrays with runs of equal elements in SAS

Tags: arrays, sas

**Case One**

Sample output:

```
`1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2......9,9,9,9,0,0,0,0'
```

A more general case would be:

The array starts with `n1` elements valued `x1`, then followed by `n2` elements valued `x2`...

In the sample output, `n1 = n2 = n3 = .. = 4`, `x1=1, x2=2 ...`

But I don't want to create it based on the element's position in array using `if-else` statement.

Here's what I have done:

```
%let nd = 80;

data _t(drop = i);
array ap{&nd};
do i = 1 to &nd;
if i le 4 then a[i] = 1;
else ....;
end;

'other codes'

run;
```

**Case Two**

What if the order in the array doesn't matter as long as it contains all the elements I need (n1 x1, n2 x2 ...) ? In this scenario, is it easier to build up the array?

Comment: How are you determining N1, N2? Your question seems unclear to me, but if it was equal groups I'd assume you could use the dim and mod functions to assign the values

Comment: @Reeze. N1,N2.. come from another dataset. Forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that you know in advance an upper bound for how many elements you want to create, you can do this in the array statement - e.g.

```
data _null_;
    array t{10} (1*1 2*2 3*3 4*4);
    put t{*};
run;
```

Output:

```
1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4
```

N.B. This sort of assignment implicitly causes your array variables to be retained.

You can also nest brackets when creating runs of elements, e.g,

```
data _null_;
    array t{10} (2*(1 2 3 4 5));
    put t{*};
run;
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5
```

However, `*` signs need to be separated by brackets, e.g.

```
data _null_;
    array t{10} (2*(1 2) 2*(3*3));
    put t{*};
run;
```

Output:

```
1 2 1 2 3 3 3 3 3 3
```